# Openstack Create server request don't work via api

Tags: rest, api, openstack

I'm trying to do a post request for creating a server inthe openstack using REST API. i tried this code (followed in the Openstack documentation) but it won't work.
Can you help please?

```
{
"server": {    "name":"auto-allocate-network",
    "imageRef":"d84ddc27-7e79-4f5f-a4fb-f5fccda375c3",
    "flavorRef":"583c710b-684b-4d05-a65c-eb69927212bd",
    "availability_zone": "nova",
    "network":"9f2989d3-c859-4ff5-ae0b-163e4562ea38"

}}
```

the URI is :

```
http://192.1.1.184:8774/v2.1/servers
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code, it works for me:

```
{
  "server": {
    "name": "test-vm1",
    "imageRef": "876d6dd5-06c7-43ea-8917-3f93ca074885",
    "flavorRef": "1",
    "max_count": 1,
    "min_count": 1,
    "networks": [
      {
        "uuid": "3b7f6755-46b1-4437-a164-5757bf0baedc"
      }
    ],
    "security_groups": [
      {
        "name": "default"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: hey are you working on OpenStack I have a problem with cloud-kitty can you help?@Mahdi Gara

Comment: yeah how can i help you ?

Comment: I was trying to install cloudkitty with devstack.can you follow https://serverfault.com/questions/857251/notimplementederror-at also some questions are posted in stackoverflow (didnt received any help) I am sure that there is some problem with horizon milestone but cloud not solve the problem can you have a look

Answer (score 0):

this [solution from @node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43998997/openstack-create-server-request-dont-work-via-api#43999139) not work for me,
and this is my result :

```
{
"choices": [
    {
        "status": "SUPPORTED",
        "media-types": [
            {
                "base": "application/json",
                "type": "application/vnd.openstack.compute+json;version=2"
            }
        ],
        "id": "v2.0",
        "links": [
            {
                "href": "http://rocky-controller.jcamp.net:8774/v2/v2.0/c0b89f614b5a457cb5acef8fe8c2b320/servers",
                "rel": "self"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "status": "CURRENT",
        "media-types": [
            {
                "base": "application/json",
                "type": "application/vnd.openstack.compute+json;version=2.1"
            }
        ],
        "id": "v2.1",
        "links": [
            {
                "href": "http://rocky-controller.jcamp.net:8774/v2.1/v2.0/c0b89f614b5a457cb5acef8fe8c2b320/servers",
                "rel": "self"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}